# Composing phrases into a grammatically correct sentence?

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, text-mining

I'm wondering if there exist any models which could take in an ordered list of phrases without punctuation and generate a grammatically correct sentence from it.

For example, for the input: ["My dog", "hates that", "guy named Michael Vick"]

The output could be either "My dog hates that guy named Michael Vick!", "My dog hates that guy named Michael Vick.", "My dog hates that guy named Michael Vick...", or even "My dog hates that guy named... Michael Vick.". Ideally, the probability of the sentence would be returned alongside the output.

Is there a specific name for this problem, so I can do a literature search myself?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are few modules implemented using TensorFlow which intended to do the same.
Example:
https://github.com/atpaino/deep-text-corrector

This deep-learning models trained to check spellings and correct small grammatical errors.

Thanks!